# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject tirando o @

Tags: json, .net, asp.net, estrutura-de-dados, newtonsoft

Estou realizando o Schema para minha pagina e preciso converter as informações para imprimi-las em JSON. Porém o **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(schema);** tira os "@" do "@context" e "@type".

**Como o código em Asp.NET esta:**

```
   #region schema
        var schema = new SchemaProduct
        {
            @context = "http://schema.org",
            @type = "Product",
            productID = productId.ToString(),
            description = funcoes.SanitizeHtml(produto.DescLonga, false),
            name = produto.Titulo,
            image = fotos,
            url = Request.Url.ToString(),
            offers = new SchemaOffer
            {
                @type = "Offer",
                areaServed = string.Format("{0}/{1}", produto.Localizacao, produto.Estado),
                category = string.Format("{0} > {1} > {2}", cat1.Nome, cat2.Nome, cat3.Nome),
                price = string.Format("{0:C}/{1}", produto.ValorVista, produto.Unidade)
            }
        };
        var text = "<script type='application/ld+json'>";
        text += Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(schema);
        text += "</script>";
        ltSchema.Text = text;
        #endregion
```

**Como é impresso:**

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
    {
    "productID":".....",
    "offers":
      {
       "type":"......",
       "price":".....",
       "areaServed":"....",
       "category":"....."
      },
    "context":"http://schema.org",
    "type":".....","url":".......",
    "image":["....."]
    }
</script>
```

Devido a isso gera a seguinte reclamação: 
[image: Teste feito no analisador de estrutura de dados do google https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de uma árdua pesquisa, achei uma solução.

Diretamente dentro das classes do Schema adicionei   **[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("@text")]**, como demonstro no exemplo abaixo:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("@context")]
public string @context { get; set; }

[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("@type")]
public string @type { get; set; }
```